# rails 3 routing question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably quite simple, but how can I make a params optional?

```
resources :places
match 'register/:id' => 'places#new', :as => :register
```

currently... it breaks if the `:id` is not passed which most of the time it won't be.

```
<%= link_to "Place Sign Up", register_path %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the last line of `config/routes.rb`

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

it uses `()` to make a param optional, in your case:

```
'register(/:id)'
```